# Exact duplicate shortcut from Eclipse in Intellij IDEA

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I am an eclipse-only programmer.
Now the time has come that I want to try out intellij IDEA to see if it may even suit me better than eclipse does now.

I have some essential shortcuts which I need to work exactly the same as I am used to. And as far as I see, that's not possible. But maybe you guys know it better.

## **1) Moving lines up and down**

In  Eclipse I use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN</kbd>:

[image]

the alt up/down could be done by IDEAs "move down/up" commands in "other":

[image]

but they behave differently. Unfortunately "too smart" I'd say... as they keep track of blank lines and skip these, and even carry comments with it. I simply want to move only the selected line, up or down, simple as that.

Example: [image]
results in

[image] and [image] when moving it up or down in Eclipse. In Intellij IDEA this happens:

[image] [image]

## **2) Duplicate Lines up and down**

In Eclipse I got these shortcuts, on copying up and the other copying down:
[image]
[image]

In Intellij IDEA I'd use the "Duplicate Entire Lines" under "Editor Actions", and this suits me very well. **BUT:** I only can use one direction, up or down, as this command only exists once. I need both... :(

---

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. IntelliJ IDEA has **Move Line Up/Down** and **Move Statement Up/Down** actions. The latter is smart, the former is dumb. Assign shortcuts and use whatever you prefer.
2. Vote for [this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-105700) or use [this third-party plug-in](https://github.com/mobile-developer/idea-duplicate-lines).

> Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA to allow copy lines and block of code like in
>   Eclipse IDE (Ctrl+Alt+UP and Ctrl+Alt+Down).

Comment: Awesome, works! I think I can live with the second point :) Thanks!